# How to find out the task dependency in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I understand that from Apache Spark you can find out dependency of among RDD inside stages by using spark history UI, like this:

[image: Details for Stage from spark history UI]

From that DAG of RDD I know that: RDD number 36 can not start before finishing RDD number 33,34 and 35.

My question is: How can I find dependency among all tasks inside specific stage?

From the spark event logs and Spark history server UI I can get the start and end time of task, But I cant find how to get dependency between tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You have already almost answered your question . You can check the `RDD` dependencies using `API` also [Spar todebug String](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@toDebugString:String) gives the facilities to check the `RDD Dependencies`. Please check [spark-rdd-dependencies](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-dependencies.html) .

At high level, when any action is called on the RDD, Spark creates the DAG and submits it to the DAG scheduler.

- The DAG scheduler divides operators into stages of tasks. A stage is comprised of tasks based on partitions of the input data. The DAG scheduler pipelines operators together. For e.g. Many map operators can be scheduled in a single stage. The final result of a DAG scheduler is a set of stages.
- The Stages are passed on to the Task Scheduler.The task scheduler launches tasks via cluster manager (Spark Standalone/Yarn/Mesos). The task scheduler doesn't know about dependencies of the stages.

At high level, there are two transformations that can be applied onto the RDDs, namely **narrow transformation and wide transformation**. Wide transformations basically result in stage boundaries.

**Narrow transformation** - doesn't require the data to be shuffled across the partitions. for example, Map, filter etc..

**wide transformation**- requires the data to be shuffled for example, reduceByKey etc..

[Advanced Apache Spark- Sameer Farooqui (Databricks) check this its best](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ooZ4S7Ay6Y)

Comment: But how about the dependency between task inside one stage? so i can make sure that the task B can not start before task A for example?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find dependency among all tasks inside specific stage?

It is simple - tasks in a single stage are always independent. They can only depend on the results of another stage.